# What alternatives are there to forums?

Tags: facebook, forum, user-forums

During a conversation about a site (with a forum) I am about to launch, a friend raised the point that Facebook and its ways have more or less killed off forums.

Probably "killed off" is too harsh in explaining it, but he did have a point. I have heard many people saying that they would rather go to a Facebook page than visit a different website. Especially the young crowds (whom my site is more or less aimed at).

I was wondering what alternative ways of involving users are out there (aside from Facebook Connect and OpenLike and the sort).

Answer (score 3):

Topic sites (such as this one). Wiki sites. Social sites with voting/commenting such as Digg / Slashdot

Comment: I like the idea of topic sites. http://bbpress.org/ is a mix,  but it's not something I can implement on the current technologies I am using. And I am certainly not going to write one for my self right away.

Answer (score 0):

You're just behind on the "scene" man, I hate it too, but Facebook IS "the computer" or "the internet" to most kids these days.

Comment: this should be a comment, you have in no way answered, or even tried to answer, the OP's question.